# Bitwise operations clarification on some cases

Tags: string, algorithm, bitwise-operators

I'm asked to use bitwise operators on char array(binary strings).
What should be the output of:

a) ~111; should the output string be 000, 1000 or something different?

b) 1010 (operator) 100; is the output the same as 1010 (operator) 0100, making those strings even with leading 0's will always work or is there a test case I am missing?

Comment: Isn't that part of your requirements?

Comment: Do you mean your numbers are stored one bit per char (with char "1" being bit 1)? If so, as Sysyphus wrote, string length is important, as long as you don't assume left extension to some specified size (as with binary integers in C). And in your b) case, the operator "a and not b" would not work as expected. You may argue it is written with two usual operators, but it really is one, and may be implemented as such (for instance *logandc2* in [Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_logand.htm)). Therefore you should be able to compute only with strings of same size.

Comment: Exactly character '1' is being binary 1. So what's the correct approach to part b then?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. After re-thinking, my program should ask users to input strings of the same length or bitwise operators can't work correctly on uneven number of bits? Right?

Comment: You may also expect string of different sizes and left-extend them with zeros so that they are the same size, before applying your operators, or even implicit fixed sized (32, 64 or whatever). It's up to you to choose your interface :-) But the least surprising would be, I think, to expect strings of same size, so yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~111 = 000

~0111 = 1000

Leading zeroes are important, because bitwise operations operate on each input bit.

Comment: and what about b) part when using 2-argument operators on uneven number of bits? should I make one longer or other one shorter?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of your bitwise operator, but generally the shorter is padded to the length of the longer.

Comment: That's what I expected. Thank You for Your time. My code will assume, that when strings are not of the same length, shorter one is missing leading zeros. Think it's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 0):

One consistent way to implement bitwise operations, including negation, on arbitrary-length bitstrings is to:

1. assume that all "normal" bitstrings implicitly have an infinite number of leading zero bits in front of them, and
2. extend the space of bitstrings you're working with to also include "negative" bitstrings that have an infinite number of *one* bits in front of them.

Thus, for example `~111` = `...1000`, where the `...1` stands for the infinite sequence of `1`-bits.

You can check for yourself that this system will satisfy all the usual rules of Boolean algebra, such as [De Morgan's laws](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
~( ~111 | ~1010 ) = ~( ...1000 | ...10101 ) = ~...11101 =   10 = 111 & 1010
~( ~111 & ~1010 ) = ~( ...1000 & ...10101 ) = ~...10000 = 1111 = 111 | 1010
```

In particular, if you're using your arbitrary-length bitstrings to represent integers in base 2 (i.e. `1` = 1, `10` = 2, `11` = 3, etc.), then the "negative bitstrings" naturally correspond to the negative numbers (e.g. `...1` = `~0` = −1, `...10` = `~1` = −2, `...101` = `~10` = −3, etc.) in generalized [two's complement](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.  Notably, this representation satisfies the general two's complement law that ~x = −x − 1.